# Is there a way to set a default value of a new column to an existing value (unique to each row) in Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table with a `DateCreated` field. I want to add another date field for sorting purposes (events can trigger a resort).

Is there a way to set the new field `DateSortBy` to be the existing value of `DateCreated` in the migration file?

My generated `Up()` function looks like this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "DateSortBy", c => c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7));
}
```

I basically want the data to look like this

```
| Id | DateCreated  | DateSortBy   |
| 01 | Feb 18, 2018 | Feb 18, 2018 |
| 02 | Feb 20, 2018 | Feb 20, 2018 |
| 03 | Feb 21, 2018 | Feb 21, 2018 |
```

Is there a way to accomplish this within the `Up()` function? I'd rather not have to write another script that I have to remember to run if I ever revert/re-implement these changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your Up() method to include a SQL statement that sets the column value in the existing rows.

So after the AddColumn command, add:

```
Sql("UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET DateSortBy = DateCreated");
```

All together, this looks like:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.MyTable", "DateSortBy", c => c.DateTimeOffset(nullable: false, precision: 7));
    Sql("UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET DateSortBy = DateCreated");
}
```